# Serve GIF from AppEngine (Python)

Tags: google-app-engine, gif

I can serve images (jpeg) from my python app engine app, using the built-in images API without problems, like so:

```
result = img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.JPEG)
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
self.response.out.write(result)
```

This does not work with GIF though. The following

```
result = img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.GIF)
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/gif'
self.response.out.write(result)
```

results in `Output encoding type not in recognized set frozenset([0, 1, 2])`

Looking at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/api/images) (near the top), I find:

```
JPEG = images_service_pb.OutputSettings.JPEG
PNG = images_service_pb.OutputSettings.PNG
WEBP = images_service_pb.OutputSettings.WEBP
BMP = -1
GIF = -2
ICO = -3
TIFF = -4

OUTPUT_ENCODING_TYPES = frozenset([JPEG, PNG, WEBP])
```

Does this mean that Serving GIFs is currently not supported by the python images api? If so, is there another way to serve gifs from a python app engine app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that Serving GIFs is currently not supported by the
>   python images api?

Yes. Confirmed by the code snippet actually producing the error you encountered, further down on the same documentation page you referenced, inside `execute_transforms_async()`:

```
    if output_encoding not in OUTPUT_ENCODING_TYPES:
      raise BadRequestError("Output encoding type not in recognized set "
                            "%s" % OUTPUT_ENCODING_TYPES)
```

> If so, is there another way to serve gifs from a python app engine
>   app?

Yes, you can use the GAE-provided [`PIL` library](http://effbot.org/zone/pil-index.htm) instead (only version 1.1.7 is available in GAE).

From [Using get_serving_url()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/#using_if_lang_is_java_getservingurl_endif_if_lang_is_python_get_serving_url_endif) (emphasis mine):

> **In addition to the Images API, you can also use** the transforms provided in the Python Imaging Library (PIL) in your Python 2.7 app.
>   To do this, declare the library in the [libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#libraries) section of the
>   `app.yaml` file. However, if you wish to use PIL in your local
>   environment (using the development server) you must also [download and
>   install PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) or [pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/) locally.
>
> The [get_serving_url()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.images#google.appengine.api.images.get_serving_url) method allows you to generate a fixed,
>   dedicated URL for an image that is stored in Blobstore.

Note: I didn't actually try this, the answer is based solely on the documentation.